# Find Middle Touch in Android

Tags: android, touch, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I'm using below method to get touch events on my android app. i need to identify middle touch. how can i identify when user touch on middle of screen ?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent mev) {
int width = v.getWidth();
int height = v.getHeight();
float x = mev.getX();
float y = mev.getY();

String msg;
if (x < width / 2) {
    if (y < height / 2)
        msg = "Top left quarter";
    else
        msg = "Bottom left quarter";

} else {
    if (y < height / 2)
        msg = "Top right quarter";
    else
        msg = "Bottom right quarter";
}

    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what 'middle' is. Let's say the middle is a 80 by 80 pixel square:

```
int midX = width / 2;
int midY = height / 2;

if (midX - 40 < x && x < midX + 40 && midY - 40 < y && y < midY + 40)
    CENTER!!!
```

Comment: i meen by **middle** is middle of whole screen

Comment: Of course, but how much of the screen is considered middle? The solution I provided means 'middle' is the 80x80 pixel in the center of the screen.